# Framer motion not animating svg layout changes

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, svg, framer-motion

I'm following the Framer Motion docs to add layout animations: https://www.framer.com/motion/layout-animations/. I am using React.

However, I can't seem to get layout animations working for `<motion.svg/>` components but it does work for `<motion.div/>` components. Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Reproducible example (click the circle SVG to trigger the animation):

`BlobSvg.tsx`:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";

import blobStyles from "./Blob.module.scss";

export const BlobSvg = () => {
  const [blobDrawn, setblobDrawn] = useState(false);

  const transition = {
    type: "spring",
  };

  const toggleBlobDrawn = () => setblobDrawn(!blobDrawn);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={blobStyles.svg_container}>
        <motion.svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          className={blobStyles.svg}
          layout
          data-blobdrawn={blobDrawn}
          transition={transition}
          onClick={toggleBlobDrawn}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={blobStyles.box_container}>
        <motion.div
          layout
          className={blobStyles.box}
          data-expanded={blobDrawn}
          transition={transition}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

`Blob.module.scss`:

```
.svg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
}

.svg[data-blobdrawn="true"] {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.svg_container {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
}

.box[data-expanded="true"] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.box_container {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG layout animations are broken
SVG components aren't currently supported with layout animations. SVGs don't have layout systems so it's recommended to directly animate their attributes like cx etc.
Its answer from documentation

Comment: Got it, do you mind linking me the documentation where it says this? Also do you know if there is a way to animate an object to a specify x, y position? I know you can animate relative x and y but what about setting the SVGs value?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).